Copilot Studio Azure Open AI Citation
My copilot studio is integrated with Azure Open AI (gpt-35-turbo) for Generative Answers.
I have configured the settings directly Copilot Studio Web and not used any APIs.
I would like my "filename" to be cited against current default "Title". What are the ways I can change the default settings.
Could someone help us with steps to change the settings for citations.
Currently I am trying to map the Search index Column of "Title" with "Filename" and yet I am receiving Title in my citation.

I am assuming you want to change the filename in the Copilot Studio. Yes you can do that.
Follow this github code in the Topic where you are processing the query and posting the response with custom name for the citation
https://github.com/pnp/powerplatform-snippets/blob/main/copilot-studio/citations-topic/source/citations.yaml
value: |-
            =[
                {
                    FileName: "Azure%20-%20Compliance%20Offerings%20(June%202024)%20(1).pdf",
                    FileUrl: "https://x.sharepoint.com/sites/KnowledgeBase/Shared%20Documents/Uploaded%20Files/Azure/Azure%20-%20Compliance%20Offerings%20(June%202024)%20(1).pdf"
                },
                {
                    FileName: "Northwind_Standard_Benefits_Details%201.pdf",
                    FileUrl: "https://x.sharepoint.com/sites/KnowledgeBase/Shared%20Documents/Uploaded%20Files/Northwind/Northwind_Standard_Benefits_Details%201.pdf"
                },
                {
                    FileName: "Northwind_Health_Plus_Benefits_Details%201.pdf",
                    FileUrl: "https://x.sharepoint.com/sites/KnowledgeBase/Shared%20Documents/Uploaded%20Files/Northwind/Northwind_Health_Plus_Benefits_Details%201.pdf"
                }    
            ]


Hi thank you for the response. However I do not wish to hardcode the filenames, since I have an indexer which runs everyday and updates my index every time a file is added in my azure blob. Since my index is updated all the time, will the above code shared would work?

I mean to say this should be a template on how to define the value in Copilot Studio. Here what you can do is call a function to get the file names and append over here to get this value dynamically and insert the citation. Hope this helps!
